# A tractor going around in the farm

Tags: grammar

1. A tractor is going around on the farm.
2. A tractor is going around in the farm.
3. A tractor is going around the farm.

Which one is a correct version, and what slight clumsiness would be added if "on" or "in" is added to?

Thank you.

Comment: The answer depends on what it is you want to say. "Around" can mean  "here and there, to various places" or "circumventing".    The driver was looking around the parking lot for an empty parking space.  There was a big pothole on the road and cars were going around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A tractor is going around on the farm.

This is OK.

> A tractor is going around in the farm.

This is also OK.  This can imply that there's a fenced off or clearly sectioned off area that the tractor is moving within.

> A tractor is going around the farm.

Context can make this mean the same as the above two sentences (esp. if someone is in the farm near the moving tractor), but it could also mean that a tractor is driving somewhere and taking a detour to avoid the farm.

Comment: Thank you, ultrasawblade. That's what I thought, but someonelse said #1 is wrong and suggested #3 instead. Why do you think that it is?

Comment: @JoeKim May I suggest that you add this to your original question so that potential answerers can tackle all of your concerns at once :-)

Comment: Thinking about it, #3 is likely most correct, especially if a farmer is involved in the conversation or the subject of farming is within the context.  (I don't talk about tractors a lot out of a farm context but it is possible.)  "Going around" can mean "covering all ground" or "checking on everything", in addition to "taking a detour to avoid an obstacle in a path".

Comment: Are you suggesting that "going around the farm" is an idiom that means "checking on everything"?  A tractor is checking on everything? Really?

Comment: The "covering all ground" meaning would be more appropriate for a tractor, obviously.